# Get a vector path from Photoshop to Inkscape or SVG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I need to extract vector paths from Photoshop into SVG format (or anything else Inkscape can use).

I don't have Illustrator, and buying it just to convert file formats seems silly.

So how can I get paths out of Photoshop into SVG?

If needed, I could write some code to manipulate files directly, but I'm not even sure where to begin to get the paths out.

Comment: Also see: [Photoshop to SVG path?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/85518/)

Answer (score 4):

**I realize this is a 2012 question... but in 2018....**

Export as SVG from Photoshop.. the paths will be there.

There may be a bunch of raster fills you'll need to remove, but the paths will all be there.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

[This tutorial](http://daringdashie.deviantart.com/art/A-rough-and-ready-guide-converting-PSD-to-SVG-311945583) seems to work, it's for Mac but you can probably replace the intermediate steps for Win.

---

I haven't try them myself, but these are some resources that might help you:

- [SVG Kit 2.0.1 for Adobe Photoshop and Adobe Photoshop Elements](http://svg.scand.com/) - Fully functional free trial
- [SVG Import/Export Converter 1.6.7](http://www.brothersoft.com/svg-import-export-converter-43134.html) - Doesn't specify PSD, but it seems free and open so worth a try.
- There is also a [Github project called psd.js](https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js), but apparently it has been "transferred" to twitpic. The [zip file is here](http://meltingice.github.com/psd.js/).
- And this [Image Converter](http://www.online-utility.org/image_converter.jsp) seems tp have PSD and SVG in the list.

If any of them help or you find an alternative way, post it for future reference :)

Comment: the last one actually works, but it converts the file to an image without any paths

Answer (score 3):

GIMP can do this. Open the .psd and go to the paths tab, there right click on any path and there is an export option.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a paths tab in gimp version 2.10. there is, however, `tools > path`, but this opens up a useless dialog window that doesn't allow you to view or edit the paths...

Comment: @user2230470 I just checked and it is still there. In the default layout it is the third tab in the top right panel (the second one after layers). You can access it in any layout via Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Paths.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop can export a SVG like @Scott mentioned. However, this may or may not be a good move for your workflow as you might need to find the path from a very large list of stuff. It is also possible to read the path info with a script, in addition to allowing you to select what to export this also allows you to customize the exporter and it works on even older versions of PS.

Since i have already [done this here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85518/photoshop-to-svg-path/85521#85521), so i am going tp just paste it verbatim here:

```
// jooExportSVGScaffold.jsx
#target photoshop

main();

function ppos(point){
    return ""+point[0]+" "+point[1] 
}


function handlePath(path) {
    var out = "";    
    var pnts = path.pathPoints;

    var ipos = pnts[0].anchor;

    var pos = pnts[0].leftDirection;
    var pos2, pos3;
    out="M"+ppos(ipos);
    for (var p=1; p<pnts.length; p++){
       pos2 = pnts[p].rightDirection;
       pos3 = pnts[p].anchor;
       out += "C"+ppos(pos)+" "+ppos(pos2)+" "+ppos(pos3);
       pos = pnts[p].leftDirection;
    }
    if (path.closed){
        pos2 = pnts[0].rightDirection;
        pos3 = pnts[0].anchor;
        out += "C"+ppos(pos)+" "+ppos(pos2)+" "+ppos(pos3)+"Z";
    }
    return out;
}

function main() {
    var sel = app.activeDocument.selection; 
    var file = File.saveDialog('save svg path', 'SVGPath:*.svg');

    file.open('w');

    file.writeln('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>');
    file.writeln('<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">');
    file.writeln('<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"');
    file.writeln('width="595.28px" height="841.89px" viewBox="0 0 595.28 841.89" enable-background="new 0 0 595.28 841.89" xml:space="preserve">');


    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var paths = doc.pathItems;

    for (var i=0; i<paths.length; i++){
        var subpaths = paths[i].subPathItems;

        for (var j=0; j<subpaths.length; j++){
            data=handlePath(subpaths[j]);  
            file.writeln('<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="'+data+'"/>');
        }
    }
    file.writeln('</svg>'); 
    file.close();
}
```

You may change the script as you see fit. Such as, instead of writing to file show it in a textbox or copy to clipboard, put a Id based on path name etc. I don't know its your workflow after all.

Comment: How do you run this code in Photoshop?

Comment: @Joe open extrendcript toolkit paste it into that and hit run, or put that in a text file with a jsx ending and drag and drop it on PS-

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not necessary to save as SVG to open the paths in Inkscape.
Photoshop/File/Export/Paths to Illustrator...
Dialog asks you which one you want to export, and then you can open AI file in Inkscape.

Comment: That's what I started with (and it's the usual way I move Photoshop paths to Corel Draw) but Inkscape doesn't recognize the AI files I'm exporting.